# send TTL pulse from Arduino at a distance of 10m reliably?

Tags: arduino, digital-communications

I am trying to send TTL pulse(HIGH and LOW, each a second wide) from Arduino reliably at a range of 10m. Is there anything I need to keep in mind while wiring such as current levels, wire types etc?

Any other information would be really helpful.

Comment: what is the frequency of the pulse?, is it possible to add additional IC on either side?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I am sending TTL pulse from arduino to raspberry pi GPIO with arduino running at baud rate of 9600.

Comment: seems like a serial data, since the distance is 10 meter, you should use some thing like RS232 or RS485 transceiver to transmit the signal to long distance (more than 100 meters) without much errors

Comment: @raj -- Are you sending 1 sec pulses or serial data at 9600baud? Confusing question..

Comment: I am sending 1 sec pulses using digital write on arduino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible without any extra circuitry. Presently, I have wired two arduino nano boards which are running at 3.3 V. Both are connected via UART lines switching at 9600 baud. The length of the cable is 19 m. I have occasionally seen errors appearing but I have error correction mechanism too.

In your case the speed is about **9600 times lesser** than mine. Hence, it will possibly work. The current shouldn't matter as long as the input is high impedance one such as opamp or other digital input lines of MCU.

If, a LED is being driven, then the resistance of wires starts to matter, but may go unnoticeable too for human eye.

If the buffer ICs are available, then you can use one and increase the speed of communication too easily.

Comment: OP stated in the question that he is sending a pulse one second wide, in the comments he says it is running at 9600baud. Confusing. Anyway, other than the 9600 times lesser statement your answer should apply to both cases.

Comment: @WesleyLee there are same names which are confusing too. Seems like three at least.

Comment: what error detection mechanism are you using?

Comment: Presently my data is 4bytes wide per packet. I perform exor bytewise and pad it as 5th byte. First two bytes are message headers. 3rd and 4th byte are data bytes. In my case, it is simple XOE checksum but is effective.